# command error in SQL Query, not sure why?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm new to SQL and I'm currently writing a query and I got this error. Any help will be appreciated.

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

My Query below:

```
CREATE VIEW moscow_paris_overlap(SSN) AS 
    SELECT t1.SSN 
    FROM assign AS T1 
    INNER JOIN assign AS T2 
    ON T1.SSN = T2.SSN 
    WHERE T1.EndYear = T2.StartYear 
    AND T1.CityName = 'Moscow' 
    AND T2.CityName = 'Paris';

    SELECT DISTINCT emp.* FROM emp INNER JOIN moscow_paris_overlap ON emp.SSN = moscow_paris_overlap.SSN;
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to separate the `CREATE VIEW` from the query which uses it. If you're using SQL*Plus or something similar you can do this by putting a `/` on a separate line between the two. This will cause the `CREATE VIEW` to be executed first.

Second, `AS` can't be used in a `FROM` or `INNER JOIN` when defining a table alias. Change the `FROM` clause in your view creation to `FROM ASSIGN T1`. Similarly, the `INNER JOIN` should be `INNER JOIN ASSIGN T2`.